# Clearing Google Colab of all installations, stored background packages causing others not to work after runtime restarted

Tags: python, pip, package, google-colaboratory, google-earth-engine

I have been using Google Colab for a while now but recently came across https://github.com/opengeos/segment-geospatial?s=03 but I cannot seem to add the raster from any of the example notebooks. I think the problem relates to previous installs of packages as even if I reset the runtime I get the below messages, of particular note is the uninstall of folium which i think might be the issue. Interesting if I use another PC then the examples work fine.

Is there a way to reset colab to its core and delete everything so starting with a blank slate, and any idea why using the same account on two different PCs that I get different results, I was under the impression that all of it was stored on cloud servers.

```
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.0->ipywidgets<8.0.0->leafmap) (1.15.1)
Requirement already satisfied: webencodings in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from bleach->nbconvert->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.0->ipywidgets<8.0.0->leafmap) (0.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from cffi>=1.0.1->argon2-cffi-bindings->argon2-cffi->notebook>=4.4.1->widgetsnbextension~=3.6.0->ipywidgets<8.0.0->leafmap) (2.21)
Installing collected packages: colour, aniso8601, xyzservices, whitebox, traittypes, snuggs, scooby, python-box, pyshp, pyproj, onnx, large-image, jedi, humanfriendly, h11, geojson, cligj, click-plugins, cachelib, affine, uvicorn, rasterio, pystac, large-image-source-gdal, fiona, coloredlogs, server-thread, pystac-client, onnxruntime, geopandas, folium, flask-restx, flask-cors, Flask-Caching, localtileserver, ipytree, ipyleaflet, ipyfilechooser, ipyevents, bqplot, whiteboxgui, leafmap, segment-anything-py, segment-geospatial
  Attempting uninstall: folium
    Found existing installation: folium 0.14.0
    Uninstalling folium-0.14.0:
      Successfully uninstalled folium-0.14.0
    Successfully installed Flask-Caching-2.0.2 affine-2.4.0 aniso8601-9.0.1 bqplot-0.12.39 cachelib-0.9.0 click-plugins-1.1.1 cligj-0.7.2 coloredlogs-15.0.1 colour-0.1.5 fiona-1.9.4 flask-cors-3.0.10 flask-restx-1.1.0 folium-0.13.0 geojson-3.0.1 geopandas-0.13.0 h11-0.14.0 humanfriendly-10.0 ipyevents-2.0.1 ipyfilechooser-0.6.0 ipyleaflet-0.17.2 ipytree-0.2.2 jedi-0.18.2 large-image-1.20.6 large-image-source-gdal-1.20.6 leafmap-0.20.2 localtileserver-0.6.4 onnx-1.14.0 onnxruntime-1.14.1 pyproj-3.5.0 pyshp-2.3.1 pystac-1.7.3 pystac-client-0.6.1 python-box-7.0.1 rasterio-1.3.6 scooby-0.7.2 segment-anything-py-1.0 segment-geospatial-0.6.2 server-thread-0.2.0 snuggs-1.4.7 traittypes-0.2.1 uvicorn-0.22.0 whitebox-2.3.1 whiteboxgui-2.3.0 xyzservices-2023.2.0
```